# Burn the "First Post" queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

**EDIT:** There was a misunderstanding... I thought first posts would be "moderated", but it appears that they appear on the site immediately.

---

What is the purpose of the "First Post" queue, really? See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23848918/754705). If you look at the first revision of it, you see that it is just an unindented code dump on a single line, with no real visible question.

So... was this post ever in the "first post" review queue?

If yes: why was it approved? and who approved it?? he should get a "first post" review ban for 3 months.

If no: why not?

I always thought the "first post" review queue would have the purpose to prevent exactly these kinds of questions. but there are so many of them.

Comment: Was this ever in the "first post" review queue? No, because this wasn't the first post by a new user. This users first post was in Jan 2014.

Comment: @bluefeet this leads me to my follow-up question ;) sorry... the question from Jan 2014 has been closed, and (in my opinion) it should never have been approved too.

Comment: @Michael: First posts aren't "moderated", they show up immediately on the site. The review queues allow people to focus on those for editing/closing/whatever needs to be done. But the reviews happen "after the fact", i.e. only once the question is visible.

Comment: @Mat oh, this explains a lot...

Comment: @Michael The post in January did hit the First Post review queue (http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3802239) and it was approved because the reviewer felt that there were no improvements needed.  The question then wound up in the Close review queue and was closed.

Comment: To extend off what @Mat said, a post has to exist for *at least* 15 minutes before it is even eligible to show up in a review queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the "First Post" queue, really?

The purpose is to help new users. Their posts go in here for their first one. This allows us to help them to learn formatting, posting, and to give them advice on any other aspect of SO that a new user may need help with.

> So... was this post ever in the "first post" review queue?

As stated by bluefeet in a comment, no because this was **not** the OP's first post. It seems that [according to the help docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) and animuson, that it isn't only the very first post but it can be more first posts until the user passes their original 1 rep (they could gain rep and go back to 1). Either way, it is a good tool to help new users.

From what I see, the OP did a code dump then went through and formatted and tried to make the question more clear.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't have to be a *first* post. Afaik as long as the user still has their original 1 reputation, they'll keep bumping to the queue. This user has more than 1, though.

Comment: @animuson thanks. I was just reading in the help center and was about to edit. It says "the first few posts" so it isn't very explicit on that. Maybe that should be more detailed? But what you said makes sense.